# Akka 2.3.14 & Java 7 - How to configure TLS

Tags: java, akka, tls1.2

I am a newbie in Akka and I implemented a TCP server which listens to device traffic. I have searched online and could not find any reference or  concrete examples of how to configure TLS using Akka IO.

My use case is that I should be able to configure multiple ports with a possibility of pointing to different key stores

I am not sure if I am missing the obvious.

I think I did not explain myself clearly so here are the details

To give you a background what I am working on and where I am stuck,

I have developed my POC using Akka IO  also, am using Akka v2.3.14 with Java 7.

What I am trying to achieve is 
  - I should be able to configure new server ports with or without TLS 
  - Each TLS port should be able to point to a unique key store file for certificates

### Actor creation path

Below is the paths of the some of the important Actors that are created

The TCPProxyService class creates the ActorSystem and loads the port configurations and then creates the ProxyServiceActor. 
The ProxyServiceActor binds to the port (Code below). When the ProxyServiceActor receives a connection it creates the ProxyActor and 
ProxyActor intern creates ProxyListenerActor and ProxySenderActor and registers the ProxyListenerActor with the tcpManager (tcpManager = Tcp.get(getSystem().manger())

> TCPProxyService ----> ProxyServiceActor(binds to the given server port) ----> ProxyActor ----> 
>   ProxyListenerActor (registered TCP listener, listens on the client port )                                                                                                                              ----> ProxySenderActor

### Sample code

The class defined below (ProxyServiceActor) is the class which binds to the port that it receives from the ProxyConfig instance which is configured using spring beans.xml

```
public class ProxyServiceActor extends UntypedActor {

    . . . .

@Override
public void preStart() throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("Listening on port = "  + proxyConfig.getPort());
    tcpManager.tell(TcpMessage.bind(getSelf(), new InetSocketAddress(proxyConfig.getListenIP(), proxyConfig.getPort()), backlog), getSelf());
}

public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {

    if (msg instanceof Connected) {
        . . . . 

        ActorRef proxy = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(ProxyActor.class),ActorConstants.PATH_PROXY+counter);

        . . . .

        proxy.tell(new Object[]{getSender(), msg}, getSelf())
    }

}
    . . . .
```

}

For each new connection, a ProxyActor instance is created and the ProxyActor creates a ProxyListenerActor instance and registers the ProxyListenerActor to listen for messages from the 
newly connected client. (Sample code below)

```
public class ProxyActor extends UntypedActor {

. . . 

public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
    if (msg instanceof Object[]) {
        . . . .

        ActorRef proxyListener = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(ProxyListenerActor.class, msg[1]),ActorConstants.PATH_PROXY_LISTENER+device.getCounter());
        . . . . 

        msg[0].tell(TcpMessage.register(proxyListener), getSelf());

        . . . .
    }
}
. . . .
```

}

The ProxyListenerActor is the class that listens on the port for messages from the client. All outbound communication is done using the ProxySenderActor

Thanks & Regards

Comment: After rethinking and researching was wondering if I can configure/ code the netty  API which Akka uses to achieve the TLS. I am now sure how efficient is this. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[Akka HTTP](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.4/scala/http/client-side/https-support.html) seems to rely on the Typesafe SSL-Config which has a detailed [coverage](http://typesafehub.github.io/ssl-config/) on the ssl configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Ion. I am currently using Akka 2.3.14.

Comment: Also,

1) I am not sure if the 2.4.4 library you pointed out will work with Akka 2.3.14. Correct me If I am wrong, v2.4.4 uses scala v2.11 and 2.3 uses v2.10
   
2) Currently, I am using Java 7.

And what I need is to be configurable at each port. What I mean is I should be able to configure a port with security and other without security.
Also, the port configuration should have the flexibility of pointing to a different certificate file (.jks)

And can you point me an example for me to better understand